# Generate navigation tree instead of crosslinks in tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht

`tex4ht` has options to create cross links betweens html pages, depending on the cut level.

Current cross-links can create next/previous/up, ... buttons and has several options to customize them.

I wanted to know if it is possible - instead of these cross links - to show the navigation as a "tree", showing only the current branch.

Example, let's say we have the following document structure

> Documentation - Table of content
>
> Chapter 1 - Overview
>
> Section 1.1 - Introduction
>
> Chapter 2 - Software
>
> Section 2.1 - Drivers
>
> Sub-section 2.1.1 - Ethernet driver
>
> Sub-section 2.1.2 - USB driver

And that `tex4ht` is used to generate HTML pages split at subsection level.

When viewing the page "Ethernet driver", I would like to see at the top:

> *documentation > 2. Software > 2.1 Drivers > 2.1.1 Ethernet driver*

Each item being a link to the related page.

Is there any standard way to do it using tex4ht or should I plan some post-processing to build that manually?

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way to do it in `tex4ht`, but it is possible to do it using some hacks. Try the following configuration file:

```
 \Preamble{xhtml}
% \TocAt{likechapter,chapter,likesection,section,likesubsubsection,subsection}
\makeatletter
\def\getsection#1{
  \expandafter\def\csname toc#1\endcsname##1##2##3{
   \edef\@tempa{##1}
   \edef\@tempb{\csname the#1\endcsname}
   \ifx\@tempb\@tempa \textgreater ##1\ ##2\fi}
}
\makeatother
\def\resetsections{%
  \def\doTocEntry{\ifx\tempa\@empty\fi}
  \def\tocpart{}
  \def\toclikepart{}
  \def\tocchapter{}
  \def\toclikechapter{}
  \def\tocsection{}
  \def\toclikesection{}
  \def\tocsubsection{}
  \def\toclikesection{}
}
\def\breadcrumbs{%
  \bgroup\resetsections\getsection{chapter}\getsection{part}\getsection{section}\getsection{subsection}%
    \HCode{<a href="\jobname.html">Main</a>}\IfFileExists{\jobname.4ct}{\input{\jobname.4ct}}{}
  \egroup%
}
\Configure{crosslinks*}{}
\Configure{crosslinks+}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="breadcrumbs">}\breadcrumbs\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

we erase default `crosslinks` definition using `\Configure{crosslinks*}{}`, then we request call to `\breadcrumbs` macro in `crosslinks+` configuration.

`\breadcrumbs` macro is little bit hacky. We exploit the TOC file generated by `tex4ht`, which is named `\jobname.4ct`. It looks like this:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname doTocEntry\endcsname\relax \expandafter\endinput\fi 
\doTocEntry\tocchapter{1}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{2}{x2-10001}{QQ2-2-1}{Overview}}{3}\relax 
\doTocEntry\tocsection{1.1}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{3}{x3-20001.1}{QQ2-3-2}{Introduction}}{3}\relax 
\doTocEntry\tocchapter{2}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{4}{x4-30002}{QQ2-4-3}{Software}}{7}\relax 
\doTocEntry\tocsection{2.1}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{5}{x5-40002.1}{QQ2-5-4}{Drivers}}{7}\relax 
\doTocEntry\tocsubsection{2.1.1}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{6}{x6-50002.1.1}{QQ2-6-5}{Ethernet driver}}{7}\relax 
\doTocEntry\tocsubsection{2.1.2}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{7}{x7-60002.1.2}{QQ2-7-6}{USB driver}}{8}\relax 
\par
```

we call macro `\resetsections`, in which we declare macros which may be containted in the `.4ct` file to do nothing, then using `\getsection`, we request testing if the included `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` equals to the current sectioning numbers. If they do, then they are printed.

A sample file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document} 
\part{Documentation}
\chapter{Overview}

 \section{Introduction}

\chapter{Software}


 \section{Drivers}

 \subsection{Ethernet driver}

 \subsection{USB driver}
hello world
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I gave it a try, and forgot that I had also several `\part` in the structure. Using your cfg file gives weird result when taking in account parts. I came with an alternative solution using a bash script with awk and string substitions to do the job.

Comment: @Blake_ch it is quite easy to add support for parts as well, see the updated answer

Comment: The generated links for parts do not match the structure with your proposal. Imagine you have \part{x} before \chapter{x} in the above structure, the links for part II Software will show Main > 1 Overview > 1.1 Introduction > II Software. I couldn't find how to fix this

Comment: @michal.h21 Please could you provide the .tex file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Arianna sure, please see the updated answer