# tex4ht manual for header, footer, toc

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, tex4ht, documentation, htlatex

I'm converting a book (6 parts, 30 sections,...) with dynamic graphs into a series of HTML pages using `tex4ht`. However, I'd like to have a nicer way to navigate. The standard is "next, prev, up, .." in header and footer. How can I manipulate that, e.g. have the name/number of the next, prev, .. element. Or maybe the entire toc in a sidebar. And I would need to add some information to the header ("Impressum") as in Germany by law one has to give the name and address of a responsible person on each website. Is there a manual for this or any idea?
Best
Christian

Comment: Is this something similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317686/trouble-building-a-site-with-frames-using-tex4ht

Comment: Thanks, I tried some of that, but without some documentation it's quite though to do more than simple copy paste

Comment: Dear Jagath, unfortunately I get two separate pages with the TOC on the left side named test2.html and the titlepage on the right side named test4.html. The file test.html on yields the switches displayed at the top.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317186/2891